# MS office help displayed as HTML

Tags: microsoft-office

Running MS Office 2010 on Win 7 64 bit.  This problem just started recently, the MS Office Help is displayed as HTML instead of text.  Get a message at top "This webpage might not be displayed properly ....... Click here for options".  When I select "Show restricted content" > Open, it changes to text.  But the next time I open Help, it's reverted back to HTML, and I have to repeat the process.  No idea what the problem might be, no luck in searching the Internet.

What I've tried:

1. Repairing MS Office
2. Delete Office (with Revo) and re-install.
3. Reset IE

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I did.  I've updated my post to show things I've tried.

Comment: This has been reported for years, and is likely an Internet Explorer problem. For example, [this forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/excel-2010-problem-loading-help-pages-restricted/0abc13e2-559e-46ab-be3b-7c704dfa6afd).

Comment: @MosheKatz - I've already tried these, to no avail.